# Как передать в функцию лямбда выражение, если она захватывает внешние переменные

Tags: c++, функции, лямбда-выражение

Есть такой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool f(double f_(int), int k) {
    if (f_(k) < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
int main() {
    int m = 3;
    auto g = [&m](int k)->double {return (double)k / 3; };
    cout << f(g, 2) << endl;
    cout << f(g, 5) << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

И он не компилится пишет:

```
Ошибка (активно)    E0413   не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "lambda []double (int k)->double" в "double (*)(int)"
```

Если написать так то всё работает (квадратные скобки пустые)

```
auto g = [](int k)->double {return (double)k / 3; };
```

Что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас лямбда с захватом - не совсем функция, а функциональный объект... Чтобы исправить ситуацию - проще всего воспользоваться шаблонами:

```
template<typename Func>
bool f(Func f_, int k) {
    if (f_(k) < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Еще вариант - использовать `function<>`:

```
bool f(function<double(int)> f_, int k) {
    if (f_(k) < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: или просто bool f(Func f_, int k) { return  f_(k) >=1; }